# Using a computer that is tethered through android phone as a fileserver?

Tags: networking, android, file-sharing, tethering

I have a rooted SII running cm12 that is providing internet/network access to my PC (which is without a wifi card currently).
I can access my home NAS from the computer if I enter it's IP address into the file browser, however I can't use it's hostname or network discovery to access it. I can live with that, however.

What is annoying, though, is that said computer has some shared folders, and I want to be able to connect to these shared folders from another machine, which I can't.

Put simply, I can do outgoing connections (connecting to NAS) from the tethered computer, however I can't connect to the tethered computer from another box on the same network as the android device.

Is there any way that I can use the android device as a switch, rather than an entire new subnet?

Comment: Being on a different subnet doesn't prevent you from connecting to shared folders either (assuming you're fine with `\\ip.addr.ess`) – it's only the fileserver's firewall that does.

Comment: @grawity okay, so the android AP is 192.168.0.124, and the computer is at 192.168.42.220. The android device is seen as the 'router' by the computer, and has the IP 192.168.42.129, however my physical router is 192.168.0.2. What IP do I use to access my computer?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I couldn't figure it out, however I have found an alternative solution for anyone who faces the same issue in the future.

LogMeIn make an awesome, free little VPN client called Hamachi, which adds a virtual network card to your computer, and lets you connect to a regular network (in my case, the android USB tethering) and it's VPN client.

You just create a free account, then create a network and add the required computers to it (up to 5). After you're set up, to browse shared folders of a computer, just right-click it in the Hamachi window and select 'Browse'. Works like a charm, and is a more than acceptable workaround.

[Hamachi website](https://www.vpn.net/)